# Getting Props value undefined in child component

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to pass a data property from parent component to child component as a props. But in child component value of props showing undefined.

```
<template>
<companyInfo :limit="this.limit"/>
</template>

data(){
  return {
     limit: 50
    }
  }
```

Child Component:

```
<template>
<div>
<p>{{ text | summary(this.limit, '...') }}</p>
</div>
</template>

data(){
        return {
            text: "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident",
        }
    },
    props: ['limit'],
    filters: {
        summary: function(text, length, suffix){
            if(!text && typeof(text) !== 'string'){
                return null;
            }else{
                return text.substr(0, length) + suffix;
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to `this.` in the template.

Parent component

```
<template>
<companyInfo :limit="limit"/>
</template>

data(){
  return {
     limit: 50
    }
  }
```

Child component

```
<template>
<div>
<p>{{ text | summary(limit, '...') }}</p>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: word limit is not working if i use only limit. as you said.

Comment: sorry i was i checking in wrong template. yah it's working. thnx.